# winforms Databining usercontrols

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have a data binding issue based on a scenario where by I have a master form Form1 and a user control CustomerDetails.
I have a gridview on my main form with just the name on it and wish to display a more detailed view in my user control.

My main form has a binding source and my usercontrol has a bindingsource on it with the various fields bound at design time:
e.g.
Firstname
Lastname
Dob
Address

I have followed the guide at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233813%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Which gives me the first record displayed correctly however when I click on a different customer on my main for the user control is not updated it remains with the original customer details

Code:FORM 1

```
    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            Dim CustomerList As New List(Of Customer)

            CustomerList.Add(New Customer With {.FirstName = "Fred", .LastName = "Bloggs"})
            CustomerList.Add(New Customer With {.FirstName = "John", .LastName = "Smith"})
            CustomerList.Add(New Customer With {.FirstName = "Harry", .LastName = "Davies"})
            CustomerList.Add(New Customer With {.FirstName = "Ben", .LastName = "Taylor"})
            CustomerList.Add(New Customer With {.FirstName = "Rob ", .LastName = "Jones"})

            CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = CustomerList

            End Sub
        End Class


    Code: CustomerDetails
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    <System.ComponentModel.ComplexBindingProperties("DataSource", "DataMember")>
    Public Class CustomerDetails

        ' DataMember Property
        Public Property DataMember() As Object
            Get
                Return CustomerBindingSource.DataMember
            End Get
            Set(value As Object)
                CustomerBindingSource.DataMember = value
            End Set
        End Property

        ' DataSource Property
        Public Property DataSource() As Object
            Get
                Return CustomerBindingSource.DataSource
            End Get
            Set(value As Object)
                CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = value
            End Set
        End Property
  End Class
```

Notes:

I am using the design time binding so would expect the relavant events to be handled automatically.

My main form has a list of customers the usercontrol has the detail view.

When you move on the list on the main form i would like the details in the usercontrol to update at the moment it stays on the first customer?

[image: Usercontrol and form]

Thanks

Rob

Comment: I am not understanding the exact problem. Can you please write more relevant code? The two blocks of code you have provided are completely unrelated to each other. Also there is no reference to the changing conditions you are mentioning. Please write a code which anyone might easily execute to reproduce your conditions.

Comment: 'click on a different customer' - Show the event code for this.

Comment: I have added some more details to the question.

Comment: I am using windows design time binding so there should be no extra code see above

Comment: The canonical way to do this entirely with design-time binding is to use a dataset containing the two tables and a datarelation between them. Then set the datasource of the child bs to the parent bs, and the datamember to the datarelation. Is this what you have done?

Comment: Its not a relation is the same data in this case a customer object, the gridview contains the overview i wish to then display the full details in the user control (it will have more fields DOB, address etc)